woocommerce_product_image_upload_error (image .avif)
I am trying to add images .avif using the Woo Commerce API, but I am getting an error:

"woocommerce_product_image_upload_error"

I've tried different ways to import, but .avif is supported and used on my site.
I've tried importing via make, via gsheet, via the native WooCommerce function, but it doesn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Had the same issue, basically the gallery images are uploading perfectly whether in avif or webP format, however, the Product Image wouldn't upload in .avif no matter what plugin I would deactivate or whatnot...
What worked for me, in Settings, changing the Modern Image Formats
Image output format from Avif to WebP. And magically (though it's likely a regression), it works again :)
enter image description here
